# How to mention in my resume that I developed a process

Tags: resume, process

In one of my jobs, I was tasked with developing an agile process for the company. The company did not follow a development process prior to that. The new process I suggested was adopted by the company and was further improved over a few months through regular feedback from team members and relevant stake holders. My key contributions were:

1. Put together an agile process that closely resembles scrum, but with some major alterations to fit the company's constraints, goals and skill level.
2. Documented the process in detail, them maintained the 'Process Document' later on.
3. Coached the entire team to gradually transition from no process to a well defined process.

I understand this sounds very similar to what an 'Agile Coach' does. I personally don't mind being called the agile coach. But I would also like to highlight the fact that I developed a process for a company where there was none. By developing a process I mean I took inspiration from well known agile methods and altered them to fit the reality of the company. How should this be mentioned in my resume?

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer:** More or less exactly as you have described it in your question.

If I read what you had in your question on your CV, I would understand exactly what you were stating you have done.  You have introduced a software development methodology based on Agile, that has been modified to suit the needs of the business.  The details of that is contained in your bullet points.

So just write more or less what you have here, prospective employers will get it :)